# An ant is to walk from $A$ to $B$. Calculate the number of paths.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

An ant has to walk from the left most lower corner to top most upper corner of $4 \times 4$ square.  However, it can take a right step or an upward step, but not necessarily in order. Calculate the number of paths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT:** In total, there are $4$ upward moves ($U$) and $4$ rightward moves ($R$). So for example $UUUURRRR$ is one of the ways ant can use. So the problem can be restated as "How many different words (meaningful or not meaningful) can be formed with $4\ U$'s and $4\ R$'s?".

Answer (score 8):

The answer to your question are [staircase walks](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StaircaseWalk.html) that are related to [Dyck paths.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DyckPath.html)

In general there are $\binom{m+n}{n}$ such paths. In your case $n=m=4$.

Comment: -1. I don't think this is the case here since ant can also go like $UUUURRRR$. I don't see a restriction that implies ant shouldn't have more upward moves than the rightward moves or something like that.

Comment: thanks... i corrected it. I have mistaken it for Dyck paths at first. But in fact they are the related staircase walks

Comment: Now +1 for the extra information.

Answer (score 4):

Whatever may be path chosen the ant has to take 4 upward steps and 4 righgward steps.

Therefore there are $\frac{8!}{4!4!}$ Paths...i,e $70$ paths

Answer (score 0):

Realise that the ant in question must take 4 steps to the right and 4 upwards. Representing a step towards right as R and an upward step as U, the ant can choose paths like RRRUUUUR, URURURUR, etc.